# google map lat long passing IOS - issue

Tags: iphone, google-maps, upgrade

we are using Google Maps to link to 'Get Directions' feature from our  IOS app.  Our app clicks over to Google map for showing directions.  We have both origin and destination lat long that we pass on.  Our format for passing data is 'originlabel@lat,long' and 'destinationlabel@lat,long'  and was working fine.  Now the get directions shows 'No Route' after we updated to latest version of Goole Maps on the iPhone.

Has anyone else face the same issue?  What is the equivalent syntax to fix this issue?  I believe if we just provide lat long it will work but I really would like a readable label attached to the data so that it is user friendly.

Please suggest...